# Set a button to disable after the first click using css

Tags: css

I'm working on this form:
https://app.couponreach.co/view-form/869/582

And I'm looking to disable the button after the first click.
The only code I can add is a css code.
Is that possible?

I'm thinking of something like:

```
.btncustom:afterclick {
pointer-events:none;
}
```

Anything to disable the button after the first click, pointer-events is an option or to make it grayed out once clicked.

Comment: Things like this aren't possible in CSS by design. CSS only cares about what to do with elements when they are in any given state. It can't control the state itself. You can change the style of the button while it's in the `:active` state. That will only change the way it looks, but not how it behaves.

Comment: Copy that, thanks for your comment. I actually have an option to put JS code along with cs code https://snipboard.io/7yJaCM.jpg would it be possible if there's a JS code?

Comment: for some cases the `:visited` might be useful  or you might even use the good old `:checked` trick : https://codepen.io/cristina-silva/pen/pyXQrj
these solutions might require you to rethink your button

Comment: if JS is an option you can just add a class to the button when clicked and select that class in CSS and disable pointer-events on it

Comment: Thanks @MaherFattouh I'll try the :visited and :checked
however, do you mind sharing a JS code that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking for a javascript solution as well, here:

**UPDATE:** used `getElementsByClassName` to disable all buttons on click of any other button.

```js
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-custom");
    
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    for(var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j++) {
        buttons[j].disabled = true;
        buttons[j].style.opacity = 0.5;
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-1 btn-custom">Button 1</button>
<button class="btn-2 btn-custom">Button 2</button>
<button class="btn-3 btn-custom">Button 3</button>
<button class="btn-4 btn-custom">Button 4</button>
```

Comment: To confirm no additional CSS code needed for this just this JS code would do right?

Comment: Yes. No css required. This would be all you need really.

Comment: looks like my button is being used as a class, not an id "<button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Confirm Reservation</button>"

Comment: getElementsByClassName() should be the correct code?

Comment: Yes. It returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name. So you need to get the element by indexing. I will update the code.

Comment: Code is updated. You can use the script now.

Comment: still not working hmm looks like I have 2 buttons to begin with: 

<div align="center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-custom btn-next" style="display:none;" onclick="goToFinalStep()">
                                Next &gt;&gt;
                            </button>
                                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom">Confirm Reservation</button>
                                                          </div>

Comment: Thank you for your response sir appreciate it.

Comment: Which button are you trying to disable?

Comment: both of it i guess?

Comment: Updated the code. It should disable all buttons on click on 1 `button`. So long as the `button` has the `class` `btn-custom`.

Comment: Thanks Prosy, you think the code button type="submit" has nothing to do with it?

Comment: No. your getting the class name. Is it still not working?

Comment: yes unfortunately it is not.
Is there any way I can put a simplest js code to test if our software is really accepting js code, to begin with?

Comment: This `<script>alert("can accept js")</script>`

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.btncustom:disabled {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementByClass("btncustom").disabled = true;
```

This code will disable the button which is enough to disable its pointer-events, but added the CSS to make it clear that you can style the disabled button (opacity, color, font or whatever)

Comment: I tried that earlier, didn't work.
Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Than you will have to use this javascript code document.getElementByClass(".btncustom").disabled = true;